# Node.js server not visible

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get node.js to run on Amazon AWS

```
 var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.write("<!DOCTYPE \"html\">");
  response.write("<html>");
  response.write("<head>");
  response.write("<title>Hello World Page</title>");
  response.write("</head>");
  response.write("<body>");
  response.write("Hello World!");
  response.write("</body>");
  response.write("</html>");
  response.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

I created the following Security groups

Inbound:
`Port Range: 8080, Destination: 0.0.0.0/0`

Outbound:
`Port Range: 8080, Destination: 0.0.0.0/0`

Node v4.4.1  is installed

Request, Express, and Socket.io are also installed

The script runs on the server without errors but it is not visible from the web?

Comment: try `curl http://localhost:8080` from the nodejs server, if this works then the problem is not in the node at all

Comment: curl http://localhost:8080 does  produce output, but the nothing appears in the browser

54.213.188.86 refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify port 8080 explicitly in the browser. Try 54.213.188.86:8080 when the server is running.

Comment: the only port that works is port 80, and I have apache running on port 80 .

Comment: When the server is running, run the `netstat -pantu | grep 8080` command and make sure that nodejs is listening on the external ip.

Comment: IN AWS Console, I figured out that each instance has a security group that appears in the last column,. all along I was opening inbound  ports to the wrong security groups.  I added port 8080 inbound port to the specific instances security group  and everything worked fine. Thanks @Pedro